# passing variable through controller method attatched to view::composer in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am trying to make commenting on my site modular, so I have attempted to use `view::composer` to run the queries that are required to populate the comment data whenever the comment view is called, then my plan was to include the comment view in any place i needed comments, and then connect it to the appropriate comment table in my database.

The functions I have made for commenting fit each of the comment tables I've created and I've made the view composer work, the only thing is now since the function to get all the comment data is being called by the view composer when the comment view is being set up, that function no longer has access to the id that was being passed to it ( normally it is in the route like: `Route::get('/{id}', 'controller@method');`).

I have been searching for hours trying to figure out how to pass the variable in, but with no luck.. Maybe I'm missing some really basic detail, Idk, but I can't figure it out and haven't found anything that solves the problem, please help..

It seems like it should be so simple, I've tried doing:

```
$var = Route::get('/{id}', function($id){ return $id; }
```

Which i thought might do it, but the result was an error saying whatever the response was couldn't be converted to string.

Comment: As per your [original post](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/27494630/1) - Your clump of letters/words is like trying to find a grain of sand amidst thousands of crawling hungry and angry army ants. Ever heard of the word "[paragraph](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paragraph)"?

Comment: You're welcome Marcus. It makes it extremely hard for us to read and to differentiate from code also. Use bacticks `\`` around code that you wish to highlight in a sentence, and 4 or more spaces followed by a line of code (on a new line) to make it look like "code" so that Stack's syntax highlighting may help us if there's a syntax error. ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Option 1: Access the route parameter

```
View::composer('comment-view', function($view){
    $id = Route::current()->getParameter('id');
});
```

#### Option 2: Use the view to access the id

In your controller: `return View::make('view-name')->with('commentId', $id);`

```
View::composer('comment-view', function($view){
    $id = $view->commentId;
});
```